# Spring Cloud Stream alternative for Micronaut

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, micronaut

we are heavily using Spring Cloud Stream with the RabbitMQ binding in our Spring Boot application. Now introducing Micronaut to a new application and really missing those lightweight spring cloud stream bindings/annotations, that generalize over rabbitmq/kafka.
Especially looking for

- automatic provisioning of exchanges/queues/DLQ with a specific naming-scheme
- lightweight destination/consumer-group setup via properties (like 2 lines and done)
- generalizing over rabbitmq, kafka-ready
- pub/sub out of the box with the consumer-groups

Comment: And now you don't even need annotations. We have moved on to functional programming model so simply defining function bean is enough to facilitate bindings and all the rest of the stuff you mentioned. There is more info in the latest docs, but feel free to ping if you need more details

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky since you are a spring maintainer, i guess by "we" you are talking about the spring-cloud-concept of functional streams. that's nice and all but we are currently based on micronaut.